# mongodb findone search NOT finding data when it should

Tags: javascript, mongodb

My MongoDB search query is finding data when it should not find with a findOne query

The query should check if there's an entry for the exact day(today)

Please advise me on how to modify the code so it finds data when and only when it needs to find

Here's the document in the database below

```
   [{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "635689a6c6741217e1322527"
  },
  "hasClockedIn": "Y",
  "clockInTime": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1666615718422"
    }
  },
  "hasClockedOut": "",
  "clockOutTime": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1666608476281"
    }
  },
  "user_id": {
    "$oid": "6356889fc6741217e13224f1"
  },
  "organisation": "KM-Cloud Technologies",
  "date_time": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1666608476281"
    }
  },
  "created_date": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1666615719000"
    }
  },
  "updated_at": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1666615719000"
    }
  },
  "__v": 0
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63595f46c29f29a3a1282499"
  },
  "hasClockedIn": "Y",
  "clockInTime": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1666801477590"
    }
  },
  "hasClockedOut": "",
  "clockOutTime": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1666801477000"
    }
  },
  "user_id": {
    "$oid": "6356889fc6741217e13224f1"
  },
  "organisation": "KM-Cloud Technologies",
  "date_time": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1666801335983"
    }
  },
  "created_date": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1666801478003"
    }
  },
  "updated_at": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1666801478003"
    }
  },
  "__v": 0
}]
```

Heres is the code to fetch the data

```
checkClockInToday: async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const today = formatDate();
        const startDay = today + "T00:00:00.000Z"
        const endDay = today + "T23:59:00.000Z"

        const attendances = await Attendance.findOne(
            {
                created_date: {
                    $gte: Date(startDay),
                    $lt: Date(endDay)
                },
                hasClockedIn: "Y",
                organisation: req.user.organisation,
                user_id: req.user._id
            }
        )
        console.log ("attendances : ", attendances)
        res.json(attendances)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.json(false)
    }
};

const  formatDate = ()=>{
    let d = new Date(),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2)
        month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2)
        day = '0' + day;

    return [year, month, day].join('-');
}
```

The issue
See the output in the logs

```
attendances :  null
```

The issue is
the output should not be what is above but instead, it should be

```
 attendances : {
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63595f46c29f29a3a1282499"
  },
  "hasClockedIn": "Y",
  "clockInTime": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1666801477590"
    }
  },
  "hasClockedOut": "",
  "clockOutTime": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1666801477000"
    }
  },
  "user_id": {
    "$oid": "6356889fc6741217e13224f1"
  },
  "organisation": "KM-Cloud Technologies",
  "date_time": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1666801335983"
    }
  },
  "created_date": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1666801478003"
    }
  },
  "updated_at": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1666801478003"
    }
  },
  "__v": 0
}
```

since there's a value for created_date that is `2022-10-26` which is today's date why am I getting null

Comment: I am a little confused here. You reference `clockInTime` and `clockOutTime` as qualifying conditions, but I don't think I see either of those fieldds referenced in the predicates used by the `findOne()` call that was shared? Similarly confusing, I see `created_at` used in the predicate but I don't see that particular field name in either the sample document or the log output. I do see `created_date` and `updated_at` though?

Comment: I edited the questing. sorry for the mix up, I am using created_date to search why is today returning nothing?

Comment: Thanks. Have you tried simplifying it down and double checking all input arguments? Your sample document seems to get returned in [this playground demonstration](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IwbahRA9u5q). I'm particularly suspicious of `user_id`, is `req.user._id` an ObjectId? Or is it coming in as a string, in which case the two types won't match.

Comment: I was missing the new keyword

Answer (score 0):

I saw the mistake
I was missing the new keyword

```
  const attendances = await Attendance.findOne(
                    {
                        clockOutTime: {
                            $gte: new Date(startDay),
                            $lt: new Date(endDay)
                        },
```